# No output when printing list of filenames

Tags: python

I am trying to print a list of image names.

The code has no error and no output. Can you help me figure out what's wrong?

```py
import cv2
path = 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\anaconda3\\envs\\X-rayProject\\Datasets/'

print(os.getcwd())
im_size = 244

images = []
labels = []

for i in room_types:
    # room_types is a list mapping the used directories
    data_path = path + str(i)
    filenames = [i for i in os.listdir(data_path)]
    for f in filenames:
        img = cv2.imread(data_path + '/' + f)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (im_size, im_size))
        images.append(img)
        labels.append(i)
```

Comment: What output did you expect?  And what is `room_types`?

Comment: the output suppose to get the name of images in array form. After this part coding I want to print(image.shape) but no output also. The room_type is function before this coding part where I just get the file names. for full coding i follow this tutorial coding https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=glmowUlqoYw&list=LL&index=9&t=1115s

Answer (score 0):

You have not imported `os` module.
`room_types` is not defined.
It should show you the above errors as it is not showing them.
I feel like you have not selected the correct interpreter.

Answer (score 0):

You were trashing your loop variable `i` in your list comprehension.  THe variable in a list comprehension is not in a private scope.  This should at least run, although I don't know what you want to do with the images you collect here.

```
import os
import cv2
path = 'C:\\Users\\Lenovo\\anaconda3\\envs\\X-rayProject\\Datasets\\'

im_size = 244

images = []
labels = []

for i in room_types:
    data_path = path + str(i) #entered file abnormal and normal
    for f in os.listdir(data_path)
        name = os.path.join(data_path, f)
        img = cv2.imread(name)
        img = cv2.resize(img, (im_size, im_size))            
        images.append(img)
        labels.append(name)

# Now you have an array of images in `images`, and an array of
# file names in `labels`.  I don't know what you want to do next.
# Presumably, you're going to process the images.

print( labels )
print( images )
```